# Convert column with strings and missings to DateTime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, error-handling

I have a dataframe with a number of dates (dtype: object) in a string format. However, from time to time, entries are missing (NaN) or they do not contain a string with a date. Here is an example:

```
data = [{"date_string" : "01:01:2019 00:00:00"}, {"date_string" : " "}, {"date_string" : np.NaN}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Converting the string to DateTime throws an error:

```
df.date_string = df.date_string.apply(pd.to_datetime)


ValueError: String does not contain a date.
```

Is there a way to bypass entries missing a date?

Comment: use `df.date_string.apply(pd.to_datetime,errors='coerce')`

Comment: worked a charme! If you like, post it as an answer and I'll mark it as complete :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the docs for [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) says:

> ```
> errors : {‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’
> If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception
> If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaT
> If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input
> ```

So you should pass `errors='coerce'` to bypass the invalid datetime values:

```
df.date_string.apply(pd.to_datetime,errors='coerce')
```

Or without apply for a single column:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date_string,errors='coerce')
```

---

```
0   2019-07-22
1          NaT
2          NaT
Name: date_string, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you! Great answer!

Comment: @Rachel no problem, i just feared its a dupe hence commented. but couldnt find any. Cheers..!!

Comment: My pleasure. I checked for dupes, too. Feel kind of stupid in any case. Rookie mistake... not reading the docs more carefully. Thank you!